# Ffmpeg adding image watermark to other images

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to add watermark to multiple images. When I add to single image I can complete the work correctly but when I try multiple ones, command prompt doesn't respond and return any error.

what I try is:

```
for f in *.png; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" "${f/%.png/-v.png}”;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You have a `”` so-called smart quote infested in your command. Use normal `"` quotes.
- The `done` is missing.

Try this:

```
for f in *.png; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" "${f/%.png/-v.png}"; done
```